# Looping over dictionary values, which are nested lists to convert into matrices

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, matrix, list-comprehension

I have the following problem:

I have a dictionary where each K,V is as follows:

k = 1 String

v = nested lists in the following manner,

inside V are A number of lists, inside each A list, there are B number of lists, inside each B list there are C number of entries.

Eventually, I would like to do some calculations of averages and standard deviations so I would like to create a dictionary where the key is the same and the v is as follows:

a matrix of A rows by B columns, where each entry in the matrix is the list B. This would allow me to arrange the data in such a way that I could remove specific values from each column of the matrix to do some calculations.

This was my reasoning, so I have tried the following:

```
#Initialzing the new dictionary
matrix_dictionary = {}

for k,v in overall_dictionary.iteritems():
    num_rows = len(v) #Number of rows in desired matrix
    for i in v:
        width = len(i) #Number of columns in desired matrix

    #Initializing the matrix
    data_matrix = [[] for i in xrange(0,width) for j in xrange(0,num_rows)]


    for y in xrange(0,height)#For row in row
        for element in v: #For each list A in v
        counter = 0; #one of indices to add element to specific spot in matrix
        for i in element:#for B list in A
            data_matrix[y][counter] = i #Trying to add list B inside matrix
            counter = counter + 1;

    matrix_dictionary[k] = data_matrix #Adding key value pair to dic
```

**Different attempt at explaining problem**

for each k in the dictionary, i have a 3D v

v for example is made up of 100 lists (A)

Each list has 50 lists (B) inside of it

Each list B has a list C, Where two indices of C are of interest

I want to create a giant table that is A rows by B columns and all of the C lists are inside

Example: first row, first column has C1, first row second column has C2, etc...

I want the matrix to then be the value in the dictionary

**I saw the following errors**

1) Index error for the matrix

2) The following works outside on its own

```
for k, v in ovarall_dictionary.iteritems():
    for A in v:
        print(A) #Prints the list A containing a bunch of lists B
    for B in A:
        print(B) #Prints each B list
```

However, the following does not work, I get index out of range for list, why?

```
z = v[0]
print(z)
```

**Eventual Goal**

For each k,v in new matrix dictionary

For each column in the matrix and within each cell for that column
get two indices X and Y

get the average of all of the X's, get the average of all the Y's

Make a new dictionary with k as string, and list of results as value pairs

**Help needed on**

I've been explained that I have a 3D array inside v: A[B[C]]]

I want to create a AxB matrix where different values of C are easily callable in the matrix

Comment: So the value of one of the items in ```overall_dictionary``` might be; ```[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]```? Which would make B = 2 and C = 2.?

Comment: You effectively have a three dimensional array for each value `v` ... state more clearly what you want to do with that array (ie what you want to calculate), and you'll get more useful help.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is: You already have your dictionary in the form you want! A list of lists ***is*** a 2D matrix.

The bad news: It's not really so clear what errors you're having and where they are coming up. More detail on that would be helpful for people to come up with solutions.

In the meantime, a few comments on your code (though I don't think it's necessary since you already have a matrix):

- You use height in your code, but never initialize it. Is height = num_rows?
- Instead of iterating through all of the rows, updating width each time, just do it once, like:

  ```
  width = len(v[0])  #This assumes all rows have same number of cols
  ```
- No need for the semi-colons. (Not that there's anything wrong with them!)
- The indentation in your code isn't clear. Make sure everything is in the right for loop.
- You should have 'for element' not 'for element a'.
- I think the counter complicates things. Try to use 'enumerate' or something like that instead.

Comment: I tried doing width = len(v[0]) but I got an error when calling v[0] saying that the list index is out of range. I don't understand why this is the case.

Yes, height = num_rows sorry about that

Comment: I am not able to replicate this error. I used

overall_dictionary = {'key1': [[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]], 'key2': [[[9,10],[11,12]], [[13,14],[15,16]]]}

And was able to access v[0] through iteritems. However, I still don't understand what you want to do. You already have a dictionary of matrices.

Comment: Using your example, what I eventually want to do is the following, if the matrix was 2x2 with [1,2] in cell 1, [3,4] in cell 2, [5,6] in cell3  etc... return a new dictionary with 'key1' but as value a list containing: average  and standard dev of each index in the columns so avg(1 and 5), avg(2 and 6), avg (3 and 7), avg(4, 8).

Comment: Okay. For this post, I think your problem is solved because you already have your matrix in a form where that is doable. I would recommend looking into the numpy library, if you haven't already.